# Android webView: websites' file upload doesn't work

Tags: android, permissions, android-webview

I have a `webView` in my app. If I open some website in it that has file upload button, which allows users to select file to upload. It works in browsers like firefox etc, but they don't work in the `webView` of my app. No file picker opens up.

Why?

Do I need to include some permission in the manifest? I already have WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.